# Find all values of a for which the equation $x^4 +(a-1)x^3 +x^2 +(a-1)x+1=0$ possesses at least two distinct negative roots

Tags: quadratics

Find all values of a for which the equation $$x^4 +(a-1)x^3 +x^2 +(a-1)x+1=0 $$ possesses at least two distinct negative roots.

I am able to prove that all roots would be negative .How to proceed after this.

Comment: It is not true that all roots must be negative.  For example, if $a=1$ there are roots near $0.531$ and $1.88$ and no negative real roots.  [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x^4-2x^3%2Bx^2-2x%2B1%3D0) is the Alpha output.

Comment: @RossMillikan if $a=1$ then the equation becomes $x^4+x^2+1=0$ which does not have any real roots since $x^4>0$ and $x^2>0$ for all values of $x$.

Comment: @SuzuHirose:  I dropped a sign.  My plot is for $a=-1$

Answer (score 6):

I decided to transform my comment into an answer.

As $x=0$ is not a root, divide the equation by $x^2$ and solve for $x+\frac{1}{x}$ as
RGB has pointed out.
You will get two solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$ for $x+\frac{1}{x}$:
$$x+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{-(a-1)-\sqrt{(a-1)^2+4}}{2}=y_1$$
and
$$x+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{-(a-1)+\sqrt{(a-1)^2+4}}{2}=y_2$$
If we want two negative roots the line $y=y_1$ must intercept twice the function $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$ in the third quadrant. That's only possible if $y_1<-2$. See the figure bellow:

[image]

So let's solve the inequality:
$$y_1<-2 \Rightarrow $$
$$\frac{-(a-1)-\sqrt{(a-1)^2+4}}{2}<-2 \Rightarrow $$
$$-(a-1)-\sqrt{(a-1)^2+4}<-4 \Rightarrow $$
$$(a-1)+\sqrt{(a-1)^2+4}>4 \Rightarrow $$
$$\sqrt{(a-1)^2+4}>5-a \Rightarrow $$
$$a^2-2a+5>25-10a+a^2 \Rightarrow $$
$$8a>20 \Rightarrow $$
$$a>\frac{5}{2}$$ 
Therefore for $a>\frac{5}{2}$ the original equation will have two negative roots.

Answer (score 4):

This is a symmetric (the coefficients) polynomial. We may want to take advantage of that. We can divide by $x^2$ and get $$(x+\frac{1}{x})^2+(a-1)(x+\frac{1}{x})-1=0$$

From there we can solve for $x+\frac{1}{x}$ and get $$x+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{-(a-1)\pm\sqrt{(a-1)^2+4}}{2}.$$

This is a quadratic equation. Solve for $x$ and get the roots.

Comment: It's not necessary to get the roots to find out the values of $a$ for which the equation has two distinct negative roots.

Comment: I know. But it is the OP who might need to know about how to do it. Tell him/her how.

Comment: @mathslover do you know for which $x<0$, $x+\frac{1}{x}$ assumes a maximum value, and how much is that value?

Comment: max value is -2. @RicardoCruz how to do otherwise

Comment: Well, @mathslover , if you impose $\frac{-(a-1)-\sqrt{(a-1)^2+4}}{2}<-2$ you will get your answer: $a>\frac{5}{2}$